# Django rest framework serialization error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django model that looks like this:

```
class AcademicProgramsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, acad_program_id, program_title, required_credits):
        return self.get(acad_program_id = acad_program_id, program_title = program_title, required_credits = required_credits)

class AcademicPrograms(models.Model):

    objects = AcademicProgramsManager()
    acad_program_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    acad_program_category = models.ForeignKey(AcademicProgramCategories)
    acad_program_type = models.ForeignKey(AcademicProgramTypes)
    acad_program_code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    program_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    required_credits = models.IntegerField()
    min_gpa = models.FloatField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.acad_program_id, self.program_title, self.required_credits)

class StudentAcademicPrograms(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Students)
    academic_program = models.ForeignKey(AcademicPrograms)
    credits_completed = models.IntegerField()
    academic_program_gpa = models.FloatField()
    primary_program = models.BooleanField()
```

This is my serializers.py file:

```
from studentapp.models import AcademicPrograms, AcademicProgramsManager, StudentAcademicPrograms
from rest_framework import serializers

class StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentAcademicPrograms
    fields = ('credits_completed','academic_program_gpa','primary_program')

class AcademicProgramsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    studentacademicprograms = StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer(many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = AcademicPrograms
        fields = ('acad_program_id','program_title','required_credits','studentacademicprograms')
```

My api.py file looks like this:

```
from studentapp.models import AcademicPrograms, AcademicProgramsManager, StudentAcademicPrograms
from studentapp.serializers import StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer, AcademicProgramsSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class AcademicProgramsList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        academicprograms = AcademicPrograms.objects.all()
        serialized_academicprograms = AcademicProgramsSerializer(academicprograms, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_academicprograms.data)

class AcademicProgramsDetail(APIView):

    def get_onjects(self, pk):
        try:
            return AcademicPrograms.object.get(pk=pk)
        except AcademicPrograms.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        academicprogram = self.get_object(pk)
        serialized_academicprogram = AcademicProgramsSerializer(academicprogram)
        return Response(serialized_academicprogram.data)
```

and finally my urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from studentapp import api

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'texascompletes.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    #API:
    url(r'^api/studentacademicprograms/$', api.AcademicProgramsList.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/studentacademicprograms/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', api.AcademicProgramsDetail.as_view()),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

I am getting the following error when i give my api/studentacademicprograms

```
'AcademicPrograms' object has no attribute 'studentacademicprograms'
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `django-rest-framework`, but looking at its docs it seems to me that you shouldn't include `studentacademicprograms` in the `AcademicProgramsSerializer.Meta.fields` list — that field list only specifies which _actual_ fields of your model to serialize, but `studentacademicprograms` is not a field on your `AcademicPrograms` model.

Comment: i was following the nested relations from this documentation. Even they used it the same way which got me confused.  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations

Comment: Their examples do not fit your scenario - their models actually contain the fields they set up for serialization.

Comment: ok..am a total newbie and so i followed the documentation. Can you give me a better way of defining my serializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `source` to the attribute/method name on the model. For example:

```
studentacademicprograms = StudentAcademicProgramsSerializer(
    many=True, 
    source='studentacademicprograms_set')
```

The example given in the [Django Rest Framework Serializer relations docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations) sets a related name on the models which matches the attribute name in the serializer (the default). If the names don't match you need to specify them model's source method/attribute to use.

Comment: hi thanks for the response. Am not sure if i am getting you right. Where exactly did u want me add it?

Comment: Change the line in `AcademicProgramsSerializer` that matches above adding the `source`. You should also remove 'studentacademicprograms' from the `fields` as it's not required (you've specified it's serialization using an attribute) and it should match the name of the reverse relationship i.e. `studentacademicprograms_set`.